# How to setup Reactjs with Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, react-router, react-router-v4

I am trying to get GA to track all my pages that are being changed by React Router v4.

I seen this code using the library: react-ga

```
history.listen(location => {
// ReactGA.set({ page: location.pathname })
// ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname)
})
```

but I don't think this will log the first page.

I seen this but I don't know how to set it up on my site

https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga/wiki/React-Router-v4-withTracker

My index.js looks like this

```
ReactDOM.render(

    <Provider routingStore={routingStore} domainStores={DomainStores} uiStores={uiStores}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={ErrorFallbackComponent}>
        <StripeProvider apiKey={stripeKey}>
          <AppContainer />
          </StripeProvider>
        </ErrorBoundary>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  ,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

then inside "appConainter" I have "Switch" with my routes in it

```
  <Switch>

          <Route
            exact
            path="n"
            component={}
          />
  </Switch>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include it in your `AppContainer` component:

`import withTracker from './withTracker'` which is a file that you manually create.

Then make the file called `withTracker.jsx` and put these contents in there:

```
import React, { Component, } from "react";
import GoogleAnalytics from "react-ga";

GoogleAnalytics.initialize("UA-0000000-0");

const withTracker = (WrappedComponent, options = {}) => {
  const trackPage = page => {
    GoogleAnalytics.set({
      page,
      ...options,
    });
    GoogleAnalytics.pageview(page);
  };

  // eslint-disable-next-line
  const HOC = class extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      const page = this.props.location.pathname + this.props.location.search;
      trackPage(page);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      const currentPage =
        prevProps.location.pathname + prevProps.location.search;
      const nextPage =
        this.props.location.pathname + this.props.location.search;

      if (currentPage !== nextPage) {
        trackPage(nextPage);
      }
    }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  };

  return HOC;
};

export default withTracker;
```

Make sure you have `react-ga` installed.

Then everywhere you have a route defined in `AppContainer` you need to call it:

`<Route component={withTracker(App, { /* additional attributes */ } )} />`

The documentation you linked shows how to do it.

Comment: Ok, so I got to put this manually on each route. I have one router that goes to another component that has more route in it. Do I pass in With Tracker or do just import "withTracker" again. <Route path="/area" render={() => <AreaComponent />} /> <- this is in my appContainer.

Comment: Also how can I make it so that this tracking will only happen when it's on production? I was before just wrapping all the GA code with a check to see with Environment is being built in  NPM

Comment: You would just need to import it again. And as for only using in production you would  probably have to make use of environment variables to tell your project which environment you are in and use a ternary statement to decide how your routes are defined depending on the environment

Comment: I have done this but I am noticing on a page I have search functionality that it causes a double render. I am wondering that it could be because I update the url(add query string of the search) and that might be some how causing it.